# Screensaver at power on

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, windows

We have a Windows 7 machine (but in the near future we may use a Windows Server one) which we use for showing a screensaver on a big display. The host is in the company domain, we log to the machine with a domain account, and we set the screensaver timeout to 1 minute. If someone get console access, to login they must know the account password, as the screensaver is password protected.

Is it possible to configure the host to autologin and autostart the password protected screensaver at power on? If so, how to?

What we would like to achieve is for the screensaver to display straight away directly from power on the information on the display, without having the requirement to have to log in, and wait one minute for the screensaver to kick in, but maintaining the screensaver password protected.

Comment: Could you set a scheduled task to start the screensaver file (*.scr) on login?

Answer (score 1):

put a shortcut to the scr file in the startup folder.  you can also change the screensaver of the login screen so no one has to log on at all.  but then you have the one minute problem again.

Answer (score 0):

To change the length of time before the logon screen saver starts, follow these steps:
Click Start, click Run, type regedt32, and then click OK.
Locate the following registry key:
HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop
In the Details pane, double-click the ScreenSaveTimeOut string value item.
In the Value data box, type the number of seconds, and then click OK.
You have now changed the length of time that elapses before the logon screen saver starts.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185348

Is that what you are after?